# Streamlining on load and on click Jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

I have some jquery I would like to streamline down into single commands of possible.

I have an on load action and a on click action that perform the same task.

This is my on load code which is checking the url for a # and then appending the background:

```
var url = document.location.href;
if (url.indexOf("#135=14") > -1) {
    jQuery('.product-header').css('background-image',
        'url("/media/product-headers/header.jpg")');
}
```

There are also buttons that perform the same task within the page and this code is:

```
jQuery('#amconf-image-14').click(function() {
    jQuery('.product-header').css('background-image',
        'url("/media/product-headers/header.jpg")');
});
```

Is there a way I can merge these two commands into a single command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function and just call that:

```
function modifyHeader() {
     jQuery('.product-header').css('background-image', 'url("/media/product-headers/header.jpg")');
}
```

And just call when needed.

```
jQuery('#amconf-image-14').click(modifyHeader);
```

Comment: That's useful to know, thanks! 

The main thing I'd like to do if possible is not have to call the instance more than once as it is used on the same page. The above does streamline the code slightly but does not combine the functions into one.

Comment: An onload and a click handler are two fundamentally different things, I'm not sure how much more combined they can be.